# File textFile.txt not found exception

Tags: java

Attempting to build a java program in eclipse that counts characters, lines, and words... When i pass the file textFile.txt in as an argument the console display this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: textFile.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at CountText.main(CountText.java:10)
```

Please let me know if you know where my issue is... Thanks in advance, code pasted below...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CountText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

            int words = 0;
            int lines = 0;
            int chars = 0;
            while(in.hasNextLine())  {
                lines++;
                String line = in.nextLine();
                chars += line.length();
                words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
            }


        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No arguments were given.");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: give the full path of the file such as c:\test/test/test.txt

Comment: try with absolute path of file

Comment: Print result of file.getAbsolutePath() and make sure that file exists in that location.

Comment: you can get your current dirrectory path using this: `new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that file `textFile.txt` is not in the current directory.

In Eclipse, you can configure what the current directory should be when running a Java program, which is done in the appropriately named "[Run Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm)", on the second tab named "Arguments".

Comment: So what should I set the directory as? Right now it is ${workspace_loc:Counter7} .... Counter7 is name of project/folder as a whole

Comment: Well, if you want a user to be able to type `textFile.txt`, you should probably set it to the folder that contains `textFile.txt`. If that's doesn't make sense, either set it to `${user.home)`, or require user to entry fully qualified file name.

Answer (score 1):

The file should exist at the location where you are working in. If you are unsure, this is the location where you are running your program from in case you are working with a command prompt. This would be your project root if you are using an IDE.

If you are still unsure, try giving absolute path like C:\filename.txt.